# How do you filter specific controls from input selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-parsing

How do you filter out specific controls from an input selection?  In the example below, radio filters but submit, button, id, etc don't seem to filter.

```
    $(':input', '#myForm')
.not('type=radio')
.not('type=submit')
.not('type=button')
.not('id="someID"');
```

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to get exactly? i think the other way round (only selecting what you need) instead of getting everything and filtering out what you don't need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this issue was specifically related to the submit button.  I tried Clive's options and when submit stayed in the list after type=submit, button and someID should have filtered it I knew something else was going on.  I looked at the selected results in the browser and discovered that it wasn't my button

My submit button:

```
<input id="submitRequest" name="submitRequest" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The outerHTML for the unwanted element:

```
outerHTML: "<input type="hidden" name="submitRequest" value="Submit">"
```

Therefore filtering out hidden got rid of this element from the selection:

```
selectedObjects2 = $(':input', '#requestAnAccountForm')
    .not('[type=radio]')
    .not('[type=hidden]');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think they should be:

```
$(':input', '#myForm')
  .not('[type=radio]')
  .not('[type=submit]')
  .not('[type=button]')
  .not('[id="someID"]');
```

Comment: Thanks.  cleaning up the synax was helpful to uncovering the submit button issue.